# When is ssh.KeyboardInteractive required?

Tags: go, ssh

https://github.com/k8gege/LadonGo/blob/main/ssh/ssh.go#L49

I see `ssh.KeyboardInteractive` is used above. But if I just use `ssh.Password` as mentioned here, I can still login to an ssh server that I test.

https://blog.ralch.com/tutorial/golang-ssh-connection/

Could anybody let me know when `ssh.KeyboardInteractive` is required and `ssh.Password` should not be used?

Comment: It’s only required if it’s the only auth accepted by the sever. Most severs won’t allow password auth. It is not uncommon to only allow publickey auth.

Comment: How to config an ssh server so that `ssh.Password` will not be accepted, but only `ssh.KeyboardInteractive` is accepted?

Comment: The documentation will help there, assuming openssh, https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthenticationMethods

Comment: When both `ssh.KeyboardInteractive` and `ssh.Password` are specified in `authMethods` as in the example code, which one is tried first?

Comment: Logically, I would assume they are tried in order, especially since the docs say only the first of a particular method will be used.

Comment: The doc says "Only the first instance of a particular RFC 4252 method will be used during authentication." But this doesn't make sense. It seems that if I disable password auth method in the server, but enable keyboard-interative, it still can authenticate. It sounds like the doc should say " the first working auth method ...".

Comment: Password and keyboard-interactive are different methods. If you added multiple password auth methods for example, only the first would be used.

Answer (score 2):

The difference in these two authentication methods (`keyboard-interactive` and `password`) [is outlined here in this Super User answer](https://superuser.com/questions/894608/ssh-o-preferredauthentications-whats-the-difference-between-password-and-k/894625).  But roughly, `password` authentication sends a single password, and `keyboard-interactive` authentication is designed for multiple prompts.

For example, you might use `keyboard-interactive` if the server wants both a password and a TOTP code to authenticate.  You can also use it in a variety of other contexts, including just a plain username and password.  Generally, if the server does PAM, then it will usually also know how to do `keyboard-interactive`.  Which one is desired on the server side is of course a matter of local policy.

Of course, typically the best practice is to avoid both of these and go for `publickey` or one of the GSSAPI (Kerberos) types instead.